# How can I use the full ksqldb client api with gradle?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

How can I use the full ksqldb client api with gradle? Why are there 2 different packages?

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://packages.confluent.io/maven/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib"
    compile group: 'io.confluent.ksql', name: 'ksqldb-api-client', version: '6.0.0'
}
```

I would like to reference v0.11.0. It contains more methods:
https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-clients/java-client/api/io/confluent/ksql/api/client/Client.html

https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/0.10.0-ksqldb/developer-guide/ksqldb-clients/java-client/api/io/confluent/ksql/api/client/Client.html

```
import io.confluent.ksql.api.client.ClientOptions
import io.confluent.ksql.api.client.*

fun main()
{
    val KSQLDB_SERVER_HOST = "localhost"
    val KSQLDB_SERVER_HOST_PORT = 8089
    
    val clientOptions = ClientOptions.create()
        .setHost(KSQLDB_SERVER_HOST)
        .setPort(KSQLDB_SERVER_HOST_PORT)

    val client: Client = io.confluent.ksql.api.client.Client.create(clientOptions)

    val topics = client.listTopics() //not available in 6.0.0
}
```

**Edit:**
Based on @Hellmar Becker's post I would like to use the standalone (community) version not the commercial Confluent Platform version. It looks like that the CP version uses an older API version anyway.

I found an example how to do this with pom.xml on Github [developer guide](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/blob/10543e19b7f1cbba46548bb7ab6cbd7d070ecbbb/docs/developer-guide/ksqldb-clients/java-client.md#getting-started), but I would like to use a build.gradle file

Comment: were you able to figure out how to get this to work? None of the answers below work for me

Answer (score 0):

There are different numbering schemes for the community licensed KSQLDB (currently v0.12) and the commercial Confluent Platform (currently v6.0.1). Maybe this comparison helps: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/ksqldb/index.html#ksqldb-standalone-and-ksqldb-for-cp.

Comment: thx Hellmar Becker. I would like to try the community edition. I suppose that it is free (not paid version). It looks like that there are even more options. My question is how to reference it in a gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to convert the pom.xml to gradle.build file from the developers guide in the following manner:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.4.21'
}

version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven() {
        url "https://ksqldb-maven.s3.amazonaws.com/maven/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib"

    implementation "io.confluent.ksql:ksqldb-api-client:0.11.0"
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```